# Julia error loading Ipopt from offline installation

Tags: julia, cluster-computing, ipopt

I have a cluster with one master and 3 compute nodes. computes have restricted access to the internet.

I installed Julia and Ipopt on the master node. then copied the entire installation to the compute nodes. Ipopt is added and built on the master.

On the master:

```
/share/apps/Julia/julia-903644385b/
Pkg.dir(): "/home/user1/.julia/v0.6"
```

On the compute:

```
partition1/apps/Julia/julia-903644385b/
Pkg.dir(): "/partition1/apps/Julia/julia-903644385b/share/julia/site/v0.6"
base=/partition1
export JULIADIR=$base/apps/Julia/julia-903644385b/
export JULIA_HOME=$JULIADIR/bin
export JULIA_PKGDIR="/partition1/apps/Julia/julia-903644385b/share/julia/site/v0.6"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JULIADIR/lib/julia:$JULIA_PKGDIR/v0.6/Ipopt/deps/usr/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$JULIADIR/bin:$PATH
```

running a sample Ipopt script is resulting in an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Unable to load
libipopt (/share/apps/Julia/julia-903644385b/share/julia/site/v0.6/Ipopt/deps/usr/lib/libipopt.so)
```

Julia on compute node is trying to pickup Ipopt from the master node. Is this matter of clearing any cache or a missing env variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the compute node, locate the file `Ipopt/deps/deps.jl`, and adapt the path where to find the `libipopt.so`:

```
# Load dependencies
@checked_lib libipopt "/full/path/to/v0.6/Ipopt/deps/usr/lib/libipopt.so"
```

Comment: Could you please help me out with this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052372/julia-error-loading-libpath47julia-so-from-offline-installation